# What is the origin of currency signs being placed before the numerical value?

Tags: language, currency, writing

For most units, they symbol/abbreviation is placed **after** the number: 200 m, 75° F, 60 mph, 100 watts, etc.

When stating values of money, such as $500, the dollar sign is placed **before** the number. This is also true of other currency signs like the euro, yuan, pound, etc.

What is the origin of this practice for currency signs?

**Edit:** As Anixx pointed out, the official ruble abbreviation (RUB) comes **after** the value. I think this is the same for all official currency abbreviations: USD, CAD, etc. But this just makes it all the more curious: why would the symbol come before the value, but the abbreviation come after the value?

BTW, I consider this an **etymology** question more than anything, but because it applies not just to English, I wonder if it had some old origin that transcends any one language (possibly in some ancient Greek or Roman practice). This is why I asked it on History.SE.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/34061/25174)?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Duplicate for English at least. I thought many other languages do or did the same thing.

Comment: I _suspect_ that there is no reason, simply convention.  Different people do things differently.

Comment: Abbreviation for ruble is usually placed after...

Comment: This question makes some unwarranted assumptions that can be seen in the link Mark C. Wallace provided.  From where I sit, this isn't a history question, it is a language / usage question, in the first place, and as written is too broad and holds assumptions that do not hold up as necessary ... it would be better to define *whose usage* originated *when* and *why* for it to get closer to a history question.

Comment: Abbreviation for US cent is placed after.  As in "5¢".   Always thought it was strange that dollar was before and cent after.

Comment: And in Spanish the rule is also to put the symbol / abbreviation after (before it was "Pta" or "Peseta", now "€" o "Euros")

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - Debatable. The top answer there is not accepted, and would probably not be considered up to our standards, as it contains no references and begins "I think that .." Also, "the origin" could be different than the "why".

Comment: FWIW, the theory there seems to be that if you are keeping books it acts as a "beginning of the amount" marker, so that nobody can fudge the books by putting an extra digit on the front. The back is protected by the decimal point. Its an attractive theory (to me as someone who wrote his Master's thesis on compiler construction anyway), but without backup its just speculation.

Comment: Probably a conversation that should be moved to meta, but I believe that the necessary preliminary research obligates OP to cite and dismiss similar questions - this question has been asked multiple times on at least 3 different SE.  When I get time I'll include the links in the question so that _the question_ contains the material needed to research & answer the question.  Sorry for discussion in comments.

Comment: @Anixx Good point. I've actually seen that for many official abbreviations: USD, CAD, RUB, etc. Those always go after the value as far as I've seen. I'll make an edit to note this.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I consider it an **etymology** question, but because it applies not just to English, I figured it had some origin many hundreds of years ago, possibly in some ancient greek or roman practice.

Comment: @DrZ214 Do you feel that Etymology is an appropriate topic for History SE?  I ask sincerely, as I'm not a long time player here.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yes, if it's cross-language, or old enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong: The position of currency symbols is not "cross-language" but rather dependent largely on language (but also on time and place, i.e. on [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software))) — contrast English and German, two languages commonly used in the Eurozone (cf. official languages of Ireland/Malta and Germany/Austria/Luxembourg/Liechtenstein/Belgium, respectively) and which therefore deal with Euro all the time:

- **English (e.g. `en_IE`):** *€2,500.00* or *2,500.00 EUR*
- **Standard High German (e.g. `de_DE`):** *2.500,00 €* or *2.500,00 EUR*

These examples are not exhaustive, but nevertheless note how these two languages differ despite not only being geographically, politically and economically close but also closely related genetically.

Note similar patterns to each language for an "exotic" currency for both languages, e.g. Japanese yen:

- **English (e.g. `en_IE`):** *¥2,500.00* or *2,500.00 JPY*
- **Standard High German (e.g. `de_DE`):** *2.500,00 ¥* or *2.500,00 JPY*

Comment: Since you mention English, just to confuse things note that older (before decimal) British money could use currency symbols before, in between, and after the amount.  E.g. £1.2s.3d = one pound, two shillings, and threepence.

Comment: Yes, but comparing cross-currency doesn't let you see that this is primarily not dependent on currency: comparing two languages with one common currency (Euro and yen) shows that the difference is actually predicted by the language used.

Comment: In Japan, assuming you're using Arabic numerals, you can usually either write it as *¥2,500.00* or *2,500.00円*.  The roles of the comma and decimal are the same as in English, and you can use the international yen sign (¥) exactly the same way; but if you use the more Japanese-style yen sign/character (円), it goes on the other side.